# Let java use 4GB of ram on Minecraft server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I have a raspberry pi 4 model B 8GB to host a Minecraft server (with Spigot). The problem is that Java return an error when I set -Xmx4096 saying : "The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size". The raspberry pi 4 model b has a 64-bit processor, then java should get more ram.

Can anyone solve my error?

Comment: https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/java-edition-support/2608616-invalid-maximum-heap-size-the-specified-size

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely on a 32bit operating system and / or using a 32bit JRE. Check this with `uname -a` and `java -version`.

Comment: you right, thank you!!!! I switched to ubuntu Serber 64bit for raspberry pi 4 and it worked! Maybe Raspberry OS is 32bit (in order to work in all devices), Idk. But installing ubuntu, I can even run with 5GB. This tiny piece of computer science will let me save a lot of money!